# How can I create this aligned bracketed thing?

Tags: tables, lists, delimiters, bigdelim

I'm trying to create a list of items that looks something like this:

[image: what i want]

but I can't figure out how to position the bracket properly. Here is what I currently have, minus the brace (which I edited into the screenshot):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{rcl}
        full-time & $\mapsto$ & $1$ \\
        \begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}}
            part-time \\
            not at all \\
            don't know
        \end{tabular} & $\mapsto$ & $0$ \\
        refused & $\mapsto$ & missing
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I'm aware of a few different solutions that take advantage of `\left. \right}` in math mode, but I can't align the text items that way. And another solution using `bigdelim` just doesn't seem to work. I'd also rather not use Tikz if I can avoid it.

Here's a more extended example that is more like what I have in my actual document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,bigdelim}
\begin{document}
Text goes here
    \begin{description}
        \item[\texttt{bigdelim}]
            \begin{itemize}
                \item[]
                \item[Sub-Thing:] Text goes here
                \item[Sub-Thing:]
                    \begin{tabular}{rcl}
                        full-time & $\mapsto$ & $1$ \\
                        part-time & & \\
                        not at all & & \\
                        don't know & $\rdelim){-3}{*}$ & \multirow{-3}{*}{$0$} \\  % rdelim} doesn't work anyway
                        refused & $\mapsto$ & missing
                    \end{tabular}
            \end{itemize}
        \item[\texttt{tabular}]
            \begin{itemize}
                \item[]
                \item[Sub-Thing:] Text goes here
                \item[Sub-Thing:]
                    \begin{tabular}{rcl}
                        full-time & $\mapsto$ & $1$ \\
                        \begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}}
                            part-time \\
                            not at all \\
                            don't know
                        \end{tabular} & $\mapsto$ & $0$ \\
                        refused & $\mapsto$ & missing
                    \end{tabular}
            \end{itemize}
    \end{description}
Text goes here
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some help from `xparse` (to easily define a `\source` command with a *-variant) and `array` for a new column type:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse,array}

\NewDocumentCommand{\source}{sm}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\bracedsource{#2}}{#2 &}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\bracedsource}{m}{%
  \global\setbox9=\hbox{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}}#1\end{tabular}%
  }%
  \copy9 & $\left.\hbox{\vphantom{\box9}}\right\rbrace$%
}

\newcolumntype{s}{r@{}c}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{scl}
\source{full-time} & $\mapsto$ & $1$ \\
\source*{
  part-time \\
  not at all \\
  don't know
}                  & $\mapsto$ & $0$ \\
\source{refused}   & $\mapsto$ & missing
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

When `\source*` is used, the argument can contain `\\` and it will produce a suitably sized brace. Note that the column containing sources has to be marked as `s` (change the character if you also load `siunitx` that preempts the column type).

[image]

Comment: Overkill but elegant and something like the Right Way

Answer (score 4):

Here you go.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,bigdelim}
\begin{document}
Text goes here
    \begin{description}
        \item[\texttt{bigdelim}]
            \begin{itemize}
                \item[]
                \item[Sub-Thing:] Text goes here
                \item[Sub-Thing:]
                    \begin{tabular}{r@{}cl}
                        full-time &  & $\mapsto 1$ \\
                        part-time & & \\
                        not at all & & \\
                        don't know & $\rdelim\}{-3}{-0.1em}$ & \multirow{-3}{*}{$\mapsto 0$} \\  % rdelim} doesn't work anyway
                        refused &  & $\mapsto$ missing
                    \end{tabular}
            \end{itemize}
        \item[\texttt{tabular}]
            \begin{itemize}
                \item[]
                \item[Sub-Thing:] Text goes here
                \item[Sub-Thing:]
                    \begin{tabular}{rcl}
                        full-time & $\mapsto$ & $1$ \\
                        \hspace{\tabcolsep}$\left.\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}}
                            part-time \\
                            not at all \\
                            don't know
                        \end{tabular}\right\}$\hspace{-\tabcolsep} & $\mapsto$ & $0$ \\
                        refused & $\mapsto$ & missing
                    \end{tabular}
            \end{itemize}
    \end{description}
Text goes here
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a version that uses `rcases*` or `drcases*` from `mathtools`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
Text goes here
    \begin{description}
        \item[\texttt{rcases}]
            \begin{itemize}
                \item[]
                \item[Sub-Thing:] Text goes here
                \item[Sub-Thing:]
                    $\begin{aligned}
                        \text{full-time} &\mapsto 1 \\
                        \begin{drcases*}
                            & part-time \\
                            & not at all \\
                            & don't know
                        \end{drcases*} & \mapsto 0 \\
                        \text{refused} & \mapsto  \text{missing}
                    \end{aligned}$
            \end{itemize}
    \end{description}
Text goes here
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like I was almost right except for a missing slash in `rdelim\}`.

Comment: @ssdecontrol You were except for `*` part which is not suitable for you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do ; maybe a less elegant :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{rcl}
        full-time & $\mapsto$ & $1$ \\
        \begin{tabular}{rl}
          part-time & \multirow{3}{*}{\Huge{$\rbrace$}} \\
          not at all & \\
          don't know & \\
        \end{tabular} & $\mapsto$ & $0$ \\
        refused & $\mapsto$ & missing
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Align brace]